# ServiceStack Uint8Array error IE9 appending parameter URL

Tags: internet-explorer-9, servicestack

I realize that on IE9, servicestack  TypeScript ServiceClient somehow is using Uint8Array to append paramter to url. Still that doest work on IE9.

http://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference

Comment: Please provide as much detail about the error that's available, what API + Request DTO causes it?

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this undefined reference issue for browsers that don't support UInt8Array in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/commit/89b2c38a5ea97cc8f2750d6e913229cf46a1eca1).

This change is now available from **v0.0.33** of [servicetack-client that's now on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/servicestack-client).